# SOQL: converting Date functions return values to specific timezone

Tags: soql, datetime, date

SOQL Date functions `CALENDAR_YEAR` and `CALENDAR_MONTH` return values as UTC Timezone values. How to convert those values to specific Timezone, like `Europe/Berlin` ?

Example time: 2014.07.01 00:00 , `Europe/Berlin` Timezone.
`CALENDAR_MONTH()` will return 6 (June, UTC Timezone) but I need to get 7.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you can't specify the TimeZone, but you could have the result to the user's timeZone.

You must use `convertTimezone`

This is un example.

```
SELECT CALENDAR_YEAR(convertTimezone(CreatedDate)), SUM(Amount)
FROM Opportunity
GROUP BY CALENDAR_YEAR(convertTimezone(CreatedDate))
```

This is the [official doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_convert_time_zone.htm) for `convertTimezone`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Martin. In my case, using convertTimezone would not help because I'm working on global Org and relying on user's timezone would lead to serious issues. What I need to do is to use a specific timezone, which is Europe/Berlin

Comment: As I told you, I think that is not possible by SOQL. I least I don't know any documented function to do that. You probably must try to get that number by APEX using `Date.format`

Comment: Strange, but CALENDAR_YEAR(convertTimezone(CreatedDate)) returns UTC timezone, not user's timezone